# Cannot prove in Dafny that f(a,b)=f(b,a)

Tags: z3, theorem-proving, dafny, termination, formal-verification

I m trying to prove in Dafny that a function is symmetric: i.e., `f(a,b)=f(b,a)`. I specify this Dafny by doing `ensures f(a,b) == f(b,a)`. However, it is not able to verify; but what I do not understand is that I get the following message: `cannot prove termination; try supplying a decreases clause`.

Since explaining my function `f` would be too verbose, I simply show the following `dummy` function:

```
function method dummy(a:real, b:real):real
   ensures dummy(a,b) == dummy(b,a)
   {
       a*b
   }
```

For which I receive the same message.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions are opaque within their own ensures clause, to avoid infinite recursion.  For example, Dafny rejects this:

```
function method dummy(x: int): int
  ensures dummy(0) == 4
{
  4
}
```

Instead, you should use a lemma:

```
function method dummy(a:real, b:real): real {
  a*b
}

lemma DummySymmetric(a:real, b:real)
  ensures dummy(a, b) == dummy(b, a)
{}
```

If you really want to get the symmetry for free without having to call a lemma, you can wrap `dummy` into another function:

```
function method dummy(a:real, b:real): real {
  a*b
}

function method dummyWithLemma(a:real, b:real): (r: real)
  ensures r == dummy(b, a)
  // ensures dummyWithLemma(a, b) == dummy(b, a) // Also OK
{
  dummy(a, b)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I only have a question left: why is different using `r=dummy(b,a)` with a `dummy(a,b)` in its body, than directly doing `dummy(a,b)=dummy(b,a)`? I mean, the body `dummy(a,b)` does not ensure termination either...

Comment: Using `r` is just more readable; it works if you write `dummyWithLemma(a, b) == dummy(b, a)` as well.  The function `dummyWithLemma` is opaque in its ensures clause, but you still know that `dummyWithLemma(a, b) == r == dummy(a, b)` (that is, you know the body of the function only for the specific arguments you're defining it with)